# fat free framework and php -S: some URLs inexplicably not working

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to run a F3 php app under `php -S`, php's builtin web server (for local testing).

I have the following routes:

```
GET /rest/1.0/team=TeamRestController->index
GET /rest/1.0/team/@id=TeamRestController->index
```

Accessing these fails with 404.

When I add these routes:

```
GET /rest/10/team=TeamRestController->index
GET /rest/10/team/@id=TeamRestController->index
```

access to them work. Looks like the dot is preventing something here. The 1.0 form does work under apache.

What is happening here?

Edit: Erm, this:

```
while (q > request->vpath) {
    if (*q-- == '.') {
        is_static_file = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

I.e. if there is a dot anywhere in the URL path then php will only serve static content, not execute scripts. What were they thinking?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in the built-in server: when calling `/rest/1.0/team`, PHP sets `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` to `/rest/1.0` even though the called script is `index.php`...

The intention is probably to support such calls: `/rest/index.php/team` but in our case, this is irrelevant since:

- the script name is already passed as an argument to the server
- there's no such script called `1.0`

You can workaround this bug by setting the correct `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` at the top of `index.php`:

```php
<?php
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=basename(__FILE__);
$f3=require('lib/base.php');
//etc...
```

Comment: In my case index.php isn't even executed - this won't workaround. I need to patch the php server code above to get anything executed - apparently it is only looking for static files where there is a dot anywhere in the path. (In my case index.php is in the root.)

Comment: How do you call `php -S`? It should look like `php -S localhost:8080 index.php`.

Comment: Without the index.php - then it almost works, as described. With the index.php it behaves completely different from under apache. (I'm not a wizard on these things.)

Comment: I encourage you to describe your issue on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/f3-framework) dedicated to the framework. That would be the proper place to debug your setup. But in short: under Apache, all requests are redirected to `index.php` thanks to [.htaccess](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/master/.htaccess) ; when using the PHP built-in server, the same is achieved by providing `index.php` as an argument of `php -S`.

Comment: I've also encountered this, and filed it in the pkp-src repo for possible attention: https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/12604